# Angular Routing when missing a trailing slash

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

I have the routing in Angular setup this way:

```
 $stateProvider
  .state('loginHome',
  {
    url: "/",
    templateUrl: "scripts/features/account/views/login.html"
  })
  .state('login',
  {
    url: "/login",
    templateUrl: "scripts/features/account/views/login.html"
  })
```

So, whenever a user navigates to:

```
http://localhost/MyApp/
http://localhost/MyApp/login
```

The login view is rendered

How do I setup a route that when a user enters the below URL, it navigates them to login:

```
http://localhost/MyApp (no trailing slash)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `otherwise()` function of `$urlRouterProvider`, please include the `$urlRouterProvider` inside the `app.config`. So that all the other unrecognized routes are sent to login page! Also there are two states for login page, instead of that you can give it as.

**JS:**

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');  
$stateProvider
  .state('login',
  {
    url: "/login",
    templateUrl: "scripts/features/account/views/login.html"
  })
```